# Tips on how to build a layout like this one

Tags: android, android-layout

Could anyone give me a tip on how to build a layout like in the following picture?

[image: Viber for android - VOIP app]

The application i'm working on has absolutely nothing to do with VoIP but I'm trying to build something like this. One fixed toolbar at the bottom, an interchangeable middle pane with listviews, scrollviews or other, and another toolbar at the top which would change depending on the button selected on the bottom bar.

Also, would it be possible and good practice to keep all of this within a single activity?

Comment: Personally I disagree with those who tell you not to create a UI like that. Who is anybody to tell anyone else what clothes to wear, how many sugars to have in their coffee, what music they should listen to and so on? If you can design your UI that way and it works for you, is intuitive to use and your users like it then that's all that counts. Just my opinion.

Comment: Problem is that it will be different than most other apps on the phone that follow the style guide and therefore be less usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should NOT build an interface like this. Don't use bottom bars! Don't use labelled back buttons on action views!

You should read the [Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) and then work with tab views... and other stuff referenced there and build an Android app.

Comment: For the record, I agree with @Manfred Moser. You should probably not  build your UI this way. My answer was just to indicate that it is indeed technically possible.

Comment: I wasn't going to use labelled back buttons. I wasn't aware of those guidelines, and I hadn't thought a bottom bar could be such an hassle, but that makes sense considering the design of some phones.

But I can but the toolbar at the top, works the same for me. And maybe then place one or two lesser used buttons at the bottom.

Any XML tips on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation and play with some examples. The UI above is pretty simple to do with a bunch of nested views in a list view and some header and footer.

Comment: What about a tabbed view (using tabActivity or other method)? I figure that should work but I've read somewhere that such class has been "deprecated".
Sorry for the hassle :\

Comment: use an actionbar with a view control for example. And read the style guide before you keep guessing. https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: I'd like to make the app compatible with earlier API's, I don't think I can use the action bar. Thanks anyway for the tip.

Comment: Use ActionBarSherlock or write dynamic wrapper yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The Android developer site is a good place to start.  See

[UI Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

I also agree with the poster who recommended against this specific layout.  It seems to have been developed for an iPhone and shouldn't be used "as is".

Answer (score 1):

> Also, would it be possible and good practice to keep all of this within a single activity?

-Yes for sure, and yes with a slight catch, depending on what you mean.

One approach would be to create your top and bottom bars inside their own XML. Then in your activity onCreate() inflate and add at the top and bottom of your Layout.

If the bottom bar will not change ever, then you could actually add that into the layouts you already have. If you do it that way, to handle the listeners you could create an Activity that contains just the bottom bar click listeners and then extend that with all of your other activities.

Since the top bar can change though you'll probably have to inflate and add the views to that at run time, that way you can react to what is going on to add / remove / present the appropriate views in the top bar.

Also just because it is somewhat of a pet peeve of mine:

When designing your bottom bar please seriously consider the fact that some devices have soft buttons directly underneath the touch screen. And they are rather close to the screen on some devices. Applications with a bottom bar that is not tall enough create an opportunity for the user to hit one of the system buttons instead of one of the bottom bar buttons as they are intending (or vice versa). Which from a users perspective I must say is VERY aggravating.

Comment: I can put the main toolbar at the top, works the same for me. Maybe I'll use the bottom for some much lesser used buttons, if needed. Would that work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use bottom bars. To give a more familiar UI, put all of those functions into the top bar. Start by looking at the source code for the ActionBarCompat project in your android sdk sample folder.